# How to present a UIAlertController from a view?

Tags: swift

Each cell in my collection view has a button and a textfield.

When the button is pressed I want to display an alert if the text field is empty.

In my custom collection view cell I have:

```
func displayAlert(title: String, error: String) {
 var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: error, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
 alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { action in
 alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
 }))
 self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func redeemButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
 if enterCodeTextField.text == "" {
  displayAlert("Something went wrong", error: "Please enter a valid code")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using alert.show() as the way to show the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your function:

```
func redeemButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
if enterCodeTextField.text == " "{

        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Alert Title here"
        alert.message = "Message Here"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Understood")
        alert.show()

    }
```